# Ansible regex_replace or regex_search

Tags: regex, ansible

I am trying to match the "OK" from the following output with regex and store it in a varible:

```
System 'server.mylabserver.com'
  status                       OK
  monitoring status            Monitored
  monitoring mode              active
  on reboot                    start
  load average                 [0.00] [0.01] [0.05]
  cpu                          0.1%us 0.1%sy 0.0%wa
  memory usage                 367.9 MB [20.0%]
  swap usage                   0 B [0.0%]
  uptime                       2h 10m
  boot time                    Mon, 02 Apr 2018 06:51:01
  data collected               Mon, 02 Apr 2018 09:01:02
```

Ansible code with "regex_replace" that I've tried:

```
  - name: Fetch the monit status
    shell: "monit status | tail -n +3"
    register: monit_status_raw
    tags: basic_monitoring
  - name: Extract monit variables
    set_fact:
        vmstatus: "{{ monit_status_raw | regex_replace('^\s\s([a-z]*)\s+', '\\1:')}}"
```

Error:

```
The offending line appears to be:

    set_fact:
       vmstatus: "{{ monit_status_raw | regex_replace('^\s\s([a-z]*)\s+', '\\1')}}"
                                                        ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Ansible code with "regex_search" that I've tried:

```
- name: Fetch the monit status
  shell: "monit status | tail -n +3"
  register: monit_status_raw
- name: Extract monit variables
  set_fact:
     vmstatus: "{{ monit_status_raw | regex_search('^\s\sstatus\s+(.*)$') }}"
```

Error:

```
The offending line appears to be:

    set_fact:
      vmstatus: "{{ monit_status_raw | regex_search('^\s\sstatus\s+(.*)$') }}"
                                                      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Any idea what it's wrong in the regexes?

Thank you,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you'd like to use regexp_search - you need to give a string and think about escaping characters, and then you need to use some construction as:

```
with_items
  - "{{ monit_status_raw.stdout_lines }}"
```

But I think it will be simpler:

```
- name: Fetch the monit status
  shell: 'monit status | tail -n +2 | grep "^\s*status" '
  register: monit_status_raw
- set_fact:
    vmstatus: "{{ monit_status_raw.stdout.split('status')[1]| replace(' ','')}}"
```

You will get vmstatus = 'Ok', if you use your sample.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the way. Is any way to change the color of the OK, for example?